# Как привязать scrollbar к listbox`у? Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

Я создал дочернее окно и там в выбранном мной пространстве расположил listbox, но scrollbar привязать к нему не могу. Получается вот такое, либо вместо списка просто scrollbar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код должен быть приведен в вопросе в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: Скорее всего нужно сначала скорлл разместить по правому краю, а потом уже листбокс.